# Placing 3 unordered lists in horizontal row

Tags: html, css, wordpress, horizontallist

I'm diving into the footer of this site for the first time, and I need to place 3 titles with phone numbers below horizontally.

I have

```
HTML:

    <div class="phone-container">
    <div class="float-left">

    <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone Central<h3></li>
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone East<h3></li>
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </div>

    CSS:

    #phone-container{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #phone-left {
        float:left; 
        width: 33%;
    }
    #phone-center { 
        float:left;
        width: 33%;
    }
    #phone-right{
        float:left;
        width: 33%;
    }
```

This is giving me all the items vertically listed towards the left, if someone knows what error I'm making or a better way to arrange these I'd love the help!

Answer (score 1):

### There's a few items to note:

**1.** Your `id` tags were not linked to the HTML elements. They need to be linked, as demonstrated below, for the styling/positioning to take effect.

**2.** The `*, :before, :after` code is for normalizing between browser behavior and for removing the extra margin that is added by default. (This allows for the 3 x 33% phone numbers to all fit on one row.

**3.** `list-style-type: none;` removes the list bullet points. You can remove the entire rule if it is something you would like to keep.

**4.** I've also went ahead and centered the phone numbers for you with `text-align: center;`.

You can see all the code, as well as how it looks like in a browser below.

In any case, if your links still need to be positioned at the bottom, you can either choose to append them to the end of your document, or `position: fix;` it to bottom of the viewport.

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#phone-container{
  width: 100%;
}

#phone-left {
  text-align: center;
  float:left; 
  width: 33.3%;
}
#phone-center { 
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
#phone-right{
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="phone-container">
  <div>
    <ul id='phone-left'>
      <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
      <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul id='phone-center'>
      <li><h3>Phone Central<h3></li>
      <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul id='phone-right'>
      <li><h3>Phone East<h3></li>
      <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd go about it. But I have issues with floats and clearing them.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone-container">
  <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>     
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone Central<h3></li>     
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><h3>Phone East<h3></li>
    <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also put

```
.phone-container{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

But then you'll need to put font sizes on your `h3` and anchors. Once you do this you'll be able to set

```
ul{
    width:33.3333333%;
}
```

And they should be evenly spaced out.

Also your HTML is not valid - you have unclosed divs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things going on here. First, you're styling the ID `#phone-container` rather than a class like you've written in your HTML, so your parent element is not getting the `width: 100%` rule applied to it.

Second, the `#phone-left`, `#phone-center`, and `#phone-right` IDs are not included in your HTML. Since these all have the same rules, I would make them all one class, `.phone`.

Check out the demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwzdeM?editors=1100).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="phone-container">
    <div class="phone">
      <ul>
        <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
        <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="phone">
      <ul>
        <li><h3>Phone Central<h3></li>
        <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="phone">
      <ul>
        <li><h3>Phone East<h3></li>
        <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{ 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

.phone-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.phone {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: I think this one is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for you-

HTML-

```
<div class="phone-container">
    <div class="float-left">
        <ul>
            <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
            <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
            <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>Phone West<h3></li>
            <li><a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#phone-container, .float-left {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#phone-container ul, .float-left ul {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#phone-container ul li, .float-left ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```